# css word wrap with hyphens

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have a line of text in a div that might look like the following:

```
A really long user defined team Name 1 (7-0)
```

Where 7-0 would be the team record.  This is in a div of a specific width and sometimes the browser likes to break on the hyphen which is unwanted because it should be treated the same as a word.  So I might end up with:

```
A really long user defined team Name 1 (7
-0)
```

Is there a way to get word wrap working where it treats the hyphen as if it were a normal character and not a place that should support a break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zfsYK/4/

**here you go..**

I just wrapped the text that you do not want to break in a div set to `display:inline`..

can't seem to make it break now

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
I added a width to the outside div: http://jsfiddle.net/zfsYK/2/
and it works great in firefox but it's still breaking in chrome for me.  Are you seeing the same?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zfsYK/4/ ok fixed just had to make it inline-block... i left inline in above for fallback when inline-block is not supported  @user417918

Comment: Dead link, please don't link to external websites or post the code here in addition.

Answer (score 6):

Although the accepted answer does te job just fine, you should consider to use the somewhat more obvious css style for this:

CSS:

```
.together {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>A really long user defined team Name 1 <span class="together">(7-0)</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, addressing this as a content issue could be more appropriate than addressing it in the presentation layer. Assuming that you want this to never be broken by word wrapping even if someone copied/pasted it out of your website and into somewhere else, replace the hyphen with a non-breaking hyphen. Unicode U+02011 which can be inserted in HTML like `A really long user defined team Name 1 (7&#8209;0)`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone is searching for a solution. You should apply `white-space: nowrap` to each of your hypened word occurrence within the text. I've made this for myself, maybe it helps:

https://jsfiddle.net/ooj6kmx1/21/

Regards